# Failing to log into loopback API using request

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, request, loopback

I'm trying to log into a loopback API I'm running on a web server using the standard `POST login` request. However every time I run it I get:

> {"error":{"statusCode":400,"name":"Error","message":"username or email is required","code":"USERNAME_EMAIL_REQUIRED"}}

I've tried logging in two ways. firstly:

```
var userDetails = {
  "email": "foo%40bar.com",
  "password": "test"
}
const requestOptions = {
  url: "APIURL/api/Users/login?email="+userDetails.email+"&password="+userDetails.password
};
request.post(requestOptions, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```

And:

```
var userDetails = {
  "email": "foo%40bar.com",
  "password": "test"
}
const requestOptions = {
  url: "https://temp-243314.appspot.com/api/Users/login",
  header: {
    "email": userDetails.email,
    "password": userDetails.password
  }
};
request.post(requestOptions, function (error, response, body) {
   console.log(body);
});
```

Where both return the same error.

Comment: Depending on the server that handles your post request (your question says put but code uses post). I think you may want to try sending user details as json body: `requestOptions = {url, body:JSON.stringify(userDetails)}` It would be helpful if we know the server code at Users/login route and what `request` is

Comment: If your request is [this one](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback), you can use `body` in request config or you can try and set `form` property.

Comment: Neither of these solutions has worked

Comment: It would be better if you updated your question with what you tried that "didn't work" and confirm what "request" you are using. At this point all anyone can do is guess.

Answer (score 1):

1. I like it when I see `;` at the end of declarations :/. your `var` declarations need a lil `;` :D
2. I'm 99% sure they are going to want that in the body. Those headers that you show in your 2nd attempt are non-standard so they would be stripped from most inbound servers (As is standard for most ingest servers like NGINX) If they wanted a custom header, they probably would have noted it like, "X-email" or something weird.
3. IF you're going to send those elements in the "body", they probably want it in JSON format, in which case you need to designate json=true in the request function.
4. If sent in the body, don't url encode with the `%40` in replacement of the `@`
   5.

```
const request = require('request');
let options = {
  uri: 'APIURL/api/Users/login',
  method: 'POST',
  json: {
    "email":"foo@bar.com",
    "password":"¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡UNHACKABLE!!!!!!!!!"
  }
};

request(options, function (err, resp, body) {
  let isHTTPSuccess;
  try {
    isHTTPSuccess = resp.statusCode + '';
    isHTTPSuccess = isHTTPSuccess[0];
    if (isHTTPSuccess === '2'){
      isHTTPSuccess = true;
    } else {
      isHTTPSuccess = false;
    }
  } catch(parseError){
    console.error(parseError);
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  if (err || !isHTTPSuccess){
    console.error(body);
    return;
  }

 console.log('WOWZER, THE CODE ABOVE IS A BIT MUCH NO? ANYWAY... HERE IS THE BODY: ', body);
 return;
});
```

6. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your request should be like:

```
var userDetails = {
  "email": "foo@bar.com",
  "password": "test"
}
```